# What am I missing to make this piece of Vb code work(VB 2005)

Tags: vb.net

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
'Do Something'
Next
```

and

```
Using f As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("somefile.txt")
    Using s As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(f)
            While Not s.EndOfStream
                    Dim line As String = s.ReadLine

                    'put you line processing code here

            End While
    End Using
End Using
```

are both showing as mostly red, I'm running a clean install of MS VS2005 and these codes were both recomended to me, am I missing something else I need to install or declare?

Comment: Dalrymple,
First of all, are you from scotland?
Secondly, remember if you copy and paste from StackOverflow.com you will need to enter the line breaks for VB.net or it wont parse correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for vb6.0 you need

```
Dim value As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

FROM Msdn you should do the following to read all lines

```
Dim Lines As String()
Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
```

For the second example something like this might work

```
Dim sr as New StreamReader("somefile.txt")
Dim line as String = sr.ReadLine()
Do While Not line is Nothing
    line = sr.ReadLine()
    'do something else
Loop
```

I just created the following VB.Net Console app and it works fine:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader("somefile.txt")
    Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
    Do While Not line Is Nothing
        line = sr.ReadLine()
        'do something else
    Loop

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Yeah even creating a new project with just that and nothing else is getting these two lines as red:
Dim sr As New StreamReader("somefile.txt")
    Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()

Comment: what kind of project are you creating?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your code surrounded by a class and method?

```
Public class CodeClass
    Public Sub CodeMethod

        Using f As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("somefile.txt")
            Using s As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(f)
                While Not s.EndOfStream
                    Dim line As String = s.ReadLine

                    //Non-vb comment for easier to read SO code
                End While
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Even just straight copying and pasting that shows error for the first line saying expected end of statement. :(

Comment: That's a hard one... anymore information you could provide to go on; such as a screen shot?

Comment: I think you are missing the line breaks Dalrymple, I copied and pasted direct from SO and found that it had stripped the line breaks.  Once I added them it worked fine.